# How to git fetch another branch after cloning a single branch

Tags: git, github

I am working in a system that automatically git clones using the --branch arg like so:

```
git clone --branch master --depth 50 git@github.com:Something/Cool.git ~/Cool
```

And I would now like to push to another branch. I can't figure out how to track the remote since git fetch and git pull don't seem to be able to access them.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying the config for each branch (or branch glob) I want to fetch. Expressed as an alias:

```
[alias]
    # Usage: git add-fetch-branch REMOTE BRANCH
    add-fetch-branch = !sh -c 'git config --add remote.$0.fetch "refs/heads/$1:refs/remotes/$0/$1"'
```

Comment: PS: I'd love to see a better answer for this. All other tries have ended up in confusing states of "not a branch", "branch not found" "can not be resolved as commit".

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way with using adding new remote so far.

So, after fetched single branch you have set the only branch for origin.

You may define new remote

```
git remote add new_scope git@git.example.com:path/to.git -t NewScope/*
```

or

```
git remote add new_branch git@git.example.com:path/to.git -t new_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [this solution](https://www.delenamalan.co.za/2019/fetch-all-branches.html) by [Delena Malan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486675/d-malan) :

> To enable fetching all branches from the remote, we can update the remote's fetch Refspec (opens new window). The Refspec is what tells git what branches to look for in the remote. We can get our remote's current Refspec like this:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch
```

> We can update the Refspec to enable fetching all branches like this:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```

> To fetch all of the remote branches, we now need to run:

```
git remote update
```

Answer (score 0):

As partly explained by other answers, the `--single-branch` or `--depth` option which implies former, restricts fetching to that single branch. So you have to change that. However, you do not need to allow fetching all branches to just fetch some. Instead you can add multiple fetch lines in remote config like this:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/16.0:refs/remotes/origin/13.0'
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/16.0:refs/remotes/origin/16.0'
```

This adds multiple fetch lines in .git/config and now to fetch new branch and track it, just run:

```
git fetch origin 13.0:13.0
git branch -u origin/13.0 13.0
```